# Detecting key presses in console

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to handle key press event in console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898182/how-to-handle-key-press-event-in-console-application)

a simple question.

I am writing a simple text based adventure game for fun and I am stuck on the first part already! How can I make my console check for key presses I.E: press enter to continue!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8898182/946904

Comment: Technically it's not, I didn't actually ask for the key to be displayed.

Comment: you are right it's not an exact duplicate but if you compare the answers here with the answers there you will see that they a very similar.

Comment: Not from C#, but in a *.cmd Windows batch script, you can use the `pause` command to halt the script execution and make it wait for any key to be pressed while displaying "Press any key to continue..." to the user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

To read 1 key. You could then do something like this:

```
string key = Console.ReadKey().Key.ToString();
if(key.ToUpper() == "W")
    Console.WriteLine("User typed 'W'!");
else 
    Console.WriteLine("User did not type 'W'");
```

Or:

```
if(key == "")
    Console.WriteLine("User pressed enter!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("User did not press enter.");
```

And if you do not care if the user types anything but presses enter after, you could just do:

```
// Some code here
Console.ReadLine();
// Code here will be run after they press enter
```

Comment: And if user presses the spacebar?

Answer (score 8):

The [Console class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43zwz7ys) contains all the methods needed to read and write to the 'console'

For example

```
Console.Write("Press Enter to continue!")  
do
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo c = Console.ReadKey();
} while (c.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.Write("Press Enter to continue!")
Console.ReadLine();
```

The program will not continue until the user hits Enter.

You can also check for other specific keys using `Console.ReadKey`:

```
void WaitForKey(ConsoleKey key)
{
    while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != key)
    { }
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.Write("Press 'Y' to continue.");
WaitForKey(ConsoleKey.Y);
```

Comment: Correct me if I Am wrong, but won't this allow it to continue no matter what is entered?

Comment: @NortonTaylor That would be weird, after saying *press enter to continue!*

Comment: @NortonTaylor: You're right that it would allow the user to continue no matter what *text* was entered; but it wouldn't continue until the user actually hit Enter. Anyway, I've added an example of a way to wait for any arbitrary key.

Comment: Alright thank you Dan :)

Comment: I appear to be having issues with actually finding waitforkey

Comment: I am assuming I am missing some imports, but I can't actually find where it's done.

Comment: @NortonTaylor: That was just a convenience function I wrote and shared with you, in case you find it useful. In other words, it's an example of a custom function you could (and probably want to, if you're writing a text adventure game) write yourself.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm a bit of a noob really and this is my stepping stone of learning some c# properly :D

Answer (score 1):

An event, that would do it.

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Key == Key.Return)
        {
            Console.Write("Press Enter to continue!")
        }
 }
```

Comment: The OP says this is a console application... EDIT: Nevermind.. you did a sneaky ninja edit!

Comment: Then in that case the `Console.ReadKey()` might be the best option.