# Check if user pressed Enter

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, console-output

**the following scenario is given:**

Welcome screen appears. If user has read the welcome text he has 2 choices:

a) pressing ENTER to continue an getting the next text

b) pressing the E-Key in oder to leave the program

**So my problem is:**

how can I check if the user pressed the ENTER-Key?

**what i tried so far - just as very primitive prototype**

...var userInput= Console.ReadLine();

```
    if (userInput == "\r")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("correct");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("wrong");
    }....
```

I also tried it via Regex but I didn't make it run. Thanks for helping...

Comment: Look into using `Console.ReadKey`. It returns a `ConsoleKey` which you could then check if it is "Enter"

Comment: Many thanks - I did try that as well. But I struggle with the part of identify the specific key "ENTER"...

Comment: _if(Console.ReadKey() == ConsoleKey.Enter)_

Comment: duplicate [Detecting key presses in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550879/detecting-key-presses-in-console)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like this (with `Console.ReadKey`):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello Mr.Sun! Try press enter now:");
    var userInput = Console.ReadKey();
    if(userInput.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed enter!");
    } else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You pressed something else");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! many thanks to all of you... super simple...! take care guys...