# Keyboard event tutorial c#

Tags: c#, events, code-snippets

Can somebody give me a snippet, about event when a user presses Down Arrow button or Up Arrow button, in console something to be triggered example

```
 Console.WriteLine("You have pressed up/down arrow ");
```

maybe that is a stupid question, but i can't find it with events but i need to be with events, any help is welcomed.

Comment: This has been asked before. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8898251/1967405

Answer (score 2):

Here's a loop which does that repeatedly until the user presses Ctrl+C:

```
while (true)
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();

    if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow || key.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have pressed up/down arrow ");
    }
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no UI events for console applications so you're stuck with `Console.ReadKey();`

Comment: Well, that's OK, can't be done something like if Console.ReadKey == ConsoleKey.UpArrow  Console.WriteLine("Up arrow is pressed");

Answer (score 0):

The console doesn't define those events. You can simulate something by using [`Console.ReadKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw.aspx). You'd have to define your own events, then:

```
var key = Console.ReadKey();
// create event parameters and dispatch the event
```

Obviously, `Console.ReadKey` blocks on the console. You can put that in a thread if you want, and dispatch the event from there. Be advised, though, that the event notification will come in on a separate thread (i.e. not the main thread).

Also, you can't have two different threads reading from the same console. Well, you *can*, but the results are unpredictable. For example, if your background thread is waiting on a `ReadKey` and another thread calls `Console.ReadLine()`, there's no telling where the input will end up.