# console application key release

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application, beep

I would like for a program to play a beep as long as a specific key is pressed.
Is there any way in which i can detect a key when it's released? and then abort a thread which plays that beep?

Consider the following example:

```
   class Program
        {
        public static void Play()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Beep(400, 10000);//play for a long length, will be interrupted as soon as the key is released
            }
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             while(true)
             {
             ConsoleKeyInfo cki=Console.ReadKey(true);
             if(cki.Key==ConsoleKey.G)
                  {
                    Thread p = new Thread(Play);
                    p.Start();
                  }

             }
        }
```

I considered using `Thread.Abort()`, However it should only abort the aforementioned thread p when the key G is released.
Implementing a method which plays the beep for a short length while keeping the G key pressed wont work , since small intervals can be heard between each beep.

Therefore, using the following code will play short beeps with small intervals between them:

```
public static void Main()
    {

        ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
        do
        {
            keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();

            Console.Beep(400, 10);
        }
        while (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.G);
    }
```

Instead i would like to have one long beep, stopped as soon as a key is released.

Comment: Check this answer, and the link for hooks http://stackoverflow.com/a/8898251/752527

Comment: try to make use of the KeyUp event handler

Comment: That will require me to use a Windows Forms Application... is there any way i could do it without it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to handle key press event in console application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898182/how-to-handle-key-press-event-in-console-application)

Comment: Doing so will make use of multiple console.beep commands which will be heard as many notes being stroked with really short intervals between them. Instead i would like to have one long Console.beep which will be heard as one long continuous beep, only stopped when a key is released

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you press and hold a key, the keyboard will generate at most about 31 "keystrokes" per second. That gives you a delay of about 32.25 ms between a keystroke and the next.

Now because the `Console.ReadKey` is blocking the thread, you will wait for this 32.25ms before invoking the next `Beep` which makes 22ms of silence for each 10ms Beep.

So back to code, you should increase the beep time to approximately match the delay between keystrokes. I spared myself the exact calculation based on `SystemInformation.KeyboardSpeed`. If you need that, I will add it.

```
ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;

do
{
    keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();

    Console.Beep(400, 33);
}
while (keyinfo.Key == ConsoleKey.G);
```

Comment: The time between the first and second keypress will vary depending on the keyboard delay and repeat rate set in the control panel.

Comment: I am afraid that it doesn't work... since Console.Beep() is blocking... so if you your system wil detect the key and then play 33 msec of beep and then stop for a while before sampling the new key... you can starting a thread for beeping asynchronously for 33 msec (or more) but I'll have to check the result... don't know what happens if two Console.Beep() calls overlap...

Comment: @MobyDisk I've just simplified that part and mentioned it in the third paragraph, that is not the core part of the solution :)

Comment: @MorixDev The thread will be blocked for 33ms on the `Beep` then will come back to `ReadKey` finding that the key press is now available. Just set your keyboard's rate at the highest and see if this works. Then I will add the calculations based on `SystemInformation.KeyboardSpeed` to make it work on any speed.

Comment: @Alireza: maybe you won't hear it... but some silence will be there for sure using such an approach...

Comment: @MorixDev My beeper is broken, so if it is not rude I will ask you to do this test on my behalf. It  will clear the matter: `while (true)  Console.Beep(33);` does this have silence in-between of the beeps?

Comment: @Alireza: I've done the test... a lot of silence between beeps on my PC... sorry!

Comment: If even this won't work, I think `Console.Beep()` is off the table and we must settle with your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It is much more complex than the other suggestes solutions but I am afraid that the only option is to play the beep from a sound buffer whose content is filled up while pressing the key... I am speaking about using DirectSound API and things like that... maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb318673(v=vs.85).aspx can be a good starting point for investigating such possibility...

Answer (score -2):

The Code you wrote works properly.

Use the Including :

**using System.Threading;**

I had run the code in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate in Any CPU build mode.

It working properly.

Run the .exe file from the project output directory.

Comment: No, it is not okay. That's what OP is telling.