# How to detect "Enter" in C# console?

Tags: c#, console, keyboard-events

I'm fairly new to C#, and I would be happy if you could help me with this.

I'm trying to detect when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed.

```
Console.Write("**Press Enter**" "to do this" or "**Press Esc**" "to do that");
```

We usually use the readline after that, but only if the user will write something.

This time I want to detect if the user has pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898182/how-to-handle-key-press-event-in-console-application) might be a better dupe target as it's specifically about console applications, where you can't really do keypress detection

Comment: The linked duplicate question is about Winforms and is not applicable for console applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey(true);

switch (cki.Key)
{
    case ConsoleKey.Enter:
        Console.WriteLine("Enter key has been pressed");
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.Escape:
        Console.WriteLine("Escape key has been pressed");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Please press Enter or Esc");
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!