# Read KeyDown in Console while the Program is Running in C#

Tags: c#, console, keypress, keyboard-events, keydown

I wrote this code for a console calculator to get math operations from the user.

Now I want to read the keyboards key like <kbd>Esc</kbd> while the program is running and at the same time as other user inputs to the calculator.

```
string func, funcText;
do
{
    funcText = Console.ReadLine();
    if (funcText.ToLower() == "esc")
        calculator.calculate();
    Console.WriteLine(math(funcText));
} while (true);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle key press event in console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898182/how-to-handle-key-press-event-in-console-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Documentation for ConsoleKeyInfo gives a decent example of how to do exactly that:

> [Source @ Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar)
>
> ```
> using System;
>
> public class Example
> {
>    public static void Main()
>    {
>       // Configure console.
>       Console.BufferWidth = 80;
>       Console.WindowWidth = Console.BufferWidth;
>       Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;
>
>       string inputString = String.Empty;
>       ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo;
>
>       Console.WriteLine("Enter a string. Press <Enter> or Esc to exit.");
>       do {
>          keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
>          // Ignore if Alt or Ctrl is pressed.
>          if ((keyInfo.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) == ConsoleModifiers.Alt) 
>             continue;
>          if ((keyInfo.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) == ConsoleModifiers.Control)
>             continue; 
>          // Ignore if KeyChar value is \u0000.
>          if (keyInfo.KeyChar == '\u0000') continue;
>          // Ignore tab key.
>          if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Tab) continue;
>          // Handle backspace.
>          if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace) {
>             // Are there any characters to erase?
>             if (inputString.Length >= 1) { 
>                // Determine where we are in the console buffer.
>                int cursorCol = Console.CursorLeft - 1;
>                int oldLength = inputString.Length;
>                int extraRows = oldLength / 80;
>
>                inputString = inputString.Substring(0, oldLength - 1);
>                Console.CursorLeft = 0;
>                Console.CursorTop = Console.CursorTop - extraRows;
>                Console.Write(inputString + new String(' ', oldLength - inputString.Length));
>                Console.CursorLeft = cursorCol;
>             }
>             continue;
>          }
>          // Handle Escape key.
>          if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
>          // Handle key by adding it to input string.
>          Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
>          inputString += keyInfo.KeyChar;
>       } while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);
>       Console.WriteLine("\n\nYou entered:\n    {0}", 
>                         String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString) ? "<nothing>" : inputString);
>    }
> }
> ```