# How do I make an action when X button pressed?

Tags: c#

I would like to know if there is a way that when you exit a console app pressing the X button, the program makes an action.

I know there is a way with Ctrl + C:

```
CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(MyHandler);
while (true)
{
    //The program code...
}

protected static void MyHandler(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs args)
{
    //Action
}
```

But I need one that work with the exit button or/and alt + F4.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898182/how-to-handle-key-press-event-in-console-application

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could [register a Control Handler Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/registering-a-control-handler-function) and handle the `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`. Here is an example to do so in C#, see [Detecting console closing in .NET](https://www.meziantou.net/detecting-console-closing-in-dotnet.htm)
 for more information and a nicer example:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32")]
private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine handlerRoutine, bool add);
private delegate bool HandlerRoutine(int signal);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(signal =>
    {
        if (signal == 2) // see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine
        {
            // TODO: handle the close event
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }, true);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```