# While pressing enter key it should display same menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am displaying menu in the console based application using C#. I want that if user press  enter key then it should display same menu. Application should not break. I am new to C#
If anyone has idea please share it. It will be helpful to me.

Below is the code.

```
public static void HospitalMenu()
{            
    string answer = "";
       
    do
    {
        Console.Clear();
           
                
        Console.WriteLine("=============Hospital Management System===================");
        Console.WriteLine("1...............Add Patient Information");
        Console.WriteLine("2...............Modify Patient Information");
        Console.WriteLine("3...............Add Patient Treatment Information");
        Console.WriteLine("4...............View Patient History");
        Console.WriteLine("5...............Search Patient Info");
        Console.WriteLine("6...............Generate Lab Report");
        Console.WriteLine("7...............Generate Medical Bills");
        Console.WriteLine("8...............Exit");


        Console.WriteLine("Select option (between 1 to 8)");
        int option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            

        switch (option)
        {
            case 1:
                Patient.InsertPatient();
                break;
            case 2:
                Patient.UpdatePatient();
                break;
            case 3:
                PatientTreatment();
                break;
             case 4:
                ViewMenu();
                break;
            case 5:
                SearchMenu();
                break;
            case 6:
                LabMenu();
                break;
            case 7:
                BillMenu();
                break;
            default:
                Environment.Exit(0);                       
                break;
        }
          

        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue ? (Enter y if yes)");
        answer = Console.ReadLine();
            

    } while (answer == "y" || answer == "Y");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle key press event in console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898182/how-to-handle-key-press-event-in-console-application)

Comment: Hope this would help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-6.0

Comment: Add `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(answer)) { answer = "y"; }` after `answer = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest some changes in your code.

Let's create an Interface that you'll be a contract responsible to show and handle inputs

**IMenuHandler.cs**

```cs
    public interface IMenuHandler<TInput>
    {
        void Show( Action stopApplicationHandler, IMenuHandler<TInput> callerMenu=null);
        void HandleInput(TInput input, Action stopApplication, IMenuHandler<TInput> callerMenu);
    }
```

Then let's create your menus.. .

As an example you'll create two, you should modify it for your needs.

**MainMenu.cs**

```cs
 public class MainMenu:IMenuHandler<ConsoleKeyInfo>
    {
        
        public void Show(Action stopApplicationHandler, IMenuHandler<ConsoleKeyInfo> callerMenu = null)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("=============Hospital Management System===================");
            Console.WriteLine("1...............Add Patient Information");
            Console.WriteLine("2...............Modify Patient Information");
            Console.WriteLine("3...............Add Patient Treatment Information");
            Console.WriteLine("4...............View Patient History");
            Console.WriteLine("5...............Search Patient Info");
            Console.WriteLine("6...............Generate Lab Report");
            Console.WriteLine("7...............Generate Medical Bills");
            Console.WriteLine("8...............Exit");
            Console.WriteLine("Select option (between 1 to 8)");
            HandleInput(Console.ReadKey(), stopApplicationHandler, callerMenu ?? this);
        }

        public void HandleInput(ConsoleKeyInfo input, Action stopApplication, IMenuHandler<ConsoleKeyInfo> callerMenu)
        {
            switch (input.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                    new HelpMenu().Show(stopApplication, callerMenu);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D8:
                    stopApplication.Invoke();
                    break;
                default:
                    Show(stopApplication, this);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**HelpMenu.cs**

```cs
public class HelpMenu:IMenuHandler<ConsoleKeyInfo>
    {


        public void Show(Action stopApplicationHandler, IMenuHandler<ConsoleKeyInfo> callerMenu = null)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Help Menu Example...");
            Console.WriteLine("1...............Go back");
            Console.WriteLine("2...............Exit");
            HandleInput(Console.ReadKey(), stopApplicationHandler, callerMenu );
        }

        public void HandleInput(ConsoleKeyInfo input, Action stopApplication, IMenuHandler<ConsoleKeyInfo> callerMenu)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Help menu handler...");
            switch (input.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                    callerMenu.Show(stopApplication, this);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D2:
                    stopApplication.Invoke();
                    break;
                default:
                    Show(stopApplication, callerMenu);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now we are going to create an wrapper for your application.

**Application.cs**

```cs
 public class Application
    {
        public delegate void OnStopApplicationRequestHandler();
        public event OnStopApplicationRequestHandler StopApplicationRequest;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

        public Application(CancellationToken? cancellationToken=null, OnStopApplicationRequestHandler? stopApplicationRequestHandler=null)
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource = cancellationToken != null 
                ? CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken.Value) 
                : new CancellationTokenSource();
            StopApplicationRequest += stopApplicationRequestHandler ?? ConfigureDefaultStopApplicationRequestHandler();
        }

        private OnStopApplicationRequestHandler ConfigureDefaultStopApplicationRequestHandler()
           => () =>
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Stopping application...");
               _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
           };
        

        public void Run()
        {
            try
            {
                while (!_cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    new MainMenu().Show(Stop);
                Console.WriteLine("Program has been stopped");
            }
            //.... You should handle other custom exceptions here
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // I'll assume that you will stop your application case it hits this unhandled exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Stop();
            }
        }

        private void Stop()
        {
            StopApplicationRequest?.Invoke();
        }

    }
```

Note that this class has an event that will be responsible to handle the application exits.

You should modify it for your needs.

### Last but not least

Call your application wrapper in your **Program.cs**

```cs
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           new Application().Run();

        }
    }
```

PS: Don't forget the correct usings....

Hope this helps